# How to pass int parameter in dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procViewAdvSearchL1]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @keyword nvarchar(800),
    @CourtID    int = null,
    @SYear int = null,
    @EYear int = null

AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[viewTextSearchL]'))
DROP VIEW [dbo].[viewTextSearchL]


Declare @sqlquery nvarchar(1500)
Set @sqlquery ='
CREATE VIEW viewTextSearchL
AS
    SELECT     tblCase.judgement_id AS ID, tblCase.case_number AS Case_No, tblCase.applicant_name AS Aplicant, tblCase.respondent_name AS Respondent, tblCase.case_date AS Case_Date, 
                  tblCourt.court_name AS Court_Name, tblCase.YearOfCase
FROM         tblCase INNER JOIN
                  tblCourt ON tblCase.court_id = tblCourt.court_id INNER JOIN
                  tblJudgement ON tblCase.judgement_id = tblJudgement.judgement_id
WHERE     CONTAINS(tblJudgement.judgement_desc,'+@keyword+') AND (CAST(tblCase.YearOfCase AS int) BETWEEN '+@SYear+' AND  '+@EYear+')' 

EXECUTE(@sqlquery)

END
```

But this gives error

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure viewTextSearchL, Line 9
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@SYear".

Comment: As it stands the params are commented out ...

Comment: Where are the `@SYear` and `@EYear` variables defined?

Comment: I hope you're washing the parameters before calling this, and not taking the keywords parameter from the users, or you have left yourself wide open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Also, *creating a view for a search result*, this is basically a single-user application then?

Comment: @AlexK., it seems to me that the parameters are not part of the sql command. As far as I am concerned, a view cannot contain parameters in its definition

Comment: Why on earth are you writing a query like this?

Comment: In the unedited question all the param declarations followed a --

Comment: @AlexK. No, they didn't. In the unedited questions the code was just not indented as code so it looked that way.

Comment: looks like this it not your complete code. For me it should give an error, but different one, conversion error from int to nvarchar. Have you tried to print or select @sqlquery to see what's going on?

Comment: I guessed that's how he was actually running it as *only* invisibility of the parameters would cause `Must declare the scalar variable "@SYear"`

Comment: You prolly also need quote @keyword in the CONTAINS call

Comment: What are the contents of @keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@CourtID    int = null,
@SYear int = null,
@EYear int = null
```

All above variable should be declare in NVARCHAR Because dynamic query 
give error except it.

```
It Should be
@CourtID    NVARCHAR(20) = null,
@SYear NVARCHAR(20) = null,
@EYear NVARCHAR(20) = null
```

Use `exec sp_execute` to execute your query except `EXECUTE(@sqlquery)`

For more details [click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Comment: I see this solution can't lead to an optimum solution to solve this issue because it will effect on the code writing to implement your sql query.So we will face a problem in maintainability. Instead I suggest to use Execute sp_Executesql passing our dynmic sql Query with your parameters list for more details kindly have a look at Example 2.1 of your article

Answer (score 1):

Based on the posted code i can only see it would get a conversion error of :

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '' to data type int.`

Use the following

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@SYear)
```

and

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@EYear)
```

Comment: but SYear and EYear are int cloumn

Comment: That is why you cast them to varchar because you cannot have int + varchar

Comment: Did you check the error? **Must declare the scalar variable "@SYear".** Your code will fail just as the original code failed. The variable is **NOT** declared for some reason

Comment: When the dynamic query runs they will be treated as int, but in order to form the dynamic query they must be converted.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is in the parameters

Comment: If it were so in the original question, the statement would compile. Check the comments. As for converting, this is done by SQL Server automatically

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It would not compile as it is an INT. Try `SELECT 'The year is ' + YEAR(GETDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is Corrected Query

```
SELECT     tblCase.judgement_id AS ID, tblCase.case_number AS Case_No, tblCase.applicant_name AS Aplicant, tblCase.respondent_name AS Respondent, tblCase.case_date AS Case_Date, 
                      tblCourt.court_name AS Court_Name, tblCase.YearOfCase
    FROM         tblCase INNER JOIN
                      tblCourt ON tblCase.court_id = tblCourt.court_id INNER JOIN
                      tblJudgement ON tblCase.judgement_id = tblJudgement.judgement_id
    WHERE     CONTAINS(tblJudgement.judgement_desc,'+@keyword+') AND (tblCase.court_id = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@CourtID)+')AND (CAST(tblCase.YearOfCase AS int) BETWEEN '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@SYear)+' AND  '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@EYear)+')'
```